# Glimpse shows negative time measurements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, web, glimpse

How is it possible, that glimpse shows negative measurements? How is the time on server measured? Is there a reason for this?

[image: glimpse screenshot]

Comment: just guessing that page requested time from server twice `dt=t1-t0` in order `t0` then do some task and then `t1` but they arrived to server in reverse order (that happens sometimes on big networks with parallel paths)

Comment: @Spektre sounds legit... anyone can confirm this assumption?

Comment: Just wondering which browser you are using?

Comment: @anthonyv in this case, Firefox was used

Comment: Is it consistently showing negative values or randomly?

Comment: @anthonyv I'm afraid, it's randomly :(